# Rpi2 raspi-config Kali : Overscan

Tags: pi-2, raspi-config, kali

I run Kali 2.0.1 on my Rpi 2. I have black areas around my main window (the PI is connected to a 1920x1080 screen), so I thought it could come from the Overscan parameter.

As you probably know, this distro doesn't provide the boot/config.txt file where one can change some parameters as overclocking, display...

So I installed raspi-config in order to fix it, but when I try to change the overscan value, I get the following error : "There was an error running option A1 overscan". I also get an error when I try to expand the file system. Overclocking seems to work (at least I don't get any error).

How can I fix my overscan problem ? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I was able to fix this by using the boot/config.txt file but note you must first mount the boot volume.

Mount the boot volume..

```
mount /mnt/mmcblk0p1
```

Create /boot/config.txt and edit it.

```
nano /boot/config.txt
```

Add the following line:

```
disable_overscan=1
```

Reboot

```
reboot now
```